# Nested For loop producing 'list index out of range' error

Tags: python, indexing

I'm trying to create set of coordinates, stored in a dictionary (each pair with a key that increases by 1 each iteration at the moment). A combination of staring at the code and manually running through each step has left me lost and stuck, if anyone can tell me where my error lies that'd be great.

```
column = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]
row = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700]
slotcounter = 0
slotdict = {}
for j in row: 
    for i in column: 
        slotcounter += 1
        coordinate = [row[j],column[i]]
        slotdict[coordinate] = slotcounter
        #print(slotdict)
```

Comment: Your iterating over your list by value, but you then you try to use the list as if your iterating by index. All you need is `coordinate = [j, i]` not `coordinate = [row[j],column[i]]` since your iterating by value, and not index.

Comment: look up 'enumermate'

Comment: @staticor `enumerate` :P

Comment: @BlaiseDeFranco What are you trying to achieve with that code? There are better ways you can do that. You should include the full context of your problem to get better suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Either you can try:

```
for j_index, j_value in enumerate(row): 
    for i_index,i_value in enumerate(column):
       .....
       # and here you can access indexes as well as value.
```

or

```
for j in range(len(row)): 
    for i in range(len(column)) :
       ...
       # here you can access indexes & by using row[j] you can get value.
```

Comment: If used right, both of your solutions would work. By why go to all that trouble when you can simply iterate by value? Not to mention I'td be more Pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

To make your code work, you'd do this:

```
for j in row:
    for i in column:
        slotcounter+=1
        coordinate = [j,i]
        slotdict[slotcounter] = coordinate
```

I'm not sure if that's what you're after though as it gives you a dictionary with 42 keys.

Answer (score 0):

Others have mentioned why your code wasn't doing what you wanted. Note that itertools.product generates the pairs for you:

```
from itertools import product

column = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600]
row = [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700]
slotcounter = 0
slotdict = {}
for coordinate in product(column, row):
   slotcounter += 1
   slotdict[coordinate] = slotcounter
```

Edit - using enumerate and dict comprehensions this can be done as a single expression:

```
slotdict = {
    coord: counter for counter, coord in enumerate(product(
        [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600],
        [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600, 700]))
}
```

Comment: Or use `enumerate` on the `product` to avoid having to manipulate the `slotcounter` yourself.